# JayData with KendoGrid: entity set events not firing? Bug?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, jaydata

If I assigned a callback to an entity set event:

```
myContext.Items.beforeDelete = function(){ alert('before delete');}
myContext.Items.beforeUpdate = function(){ alert('before update');}
```

I get the alert messages if I delete or update a record. But if I use that entity set with a Kendo grid, I do not get any of the events? Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

```
dataSource: myContext.Items.filter('it.IsDeleted == false').asKendoDataSource();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (or work around) is to use the Entity Type events instead of the Entity Set events. I am not sure if this is a bug or not, but there is a clear work around.

See:
http://jaydata.org/blog/jaydata-event-handlers

Answer (score 1):

You've found the [correct post](http://jaydata.org/blog/jaydata-event-handlers), but it's the documentation not a workaround :).

The code you've tried isn't working probably because you should have written it **before** creating an instance of the context (for example by assigning the event handler in the model definition just like in the docs).